# It's ok to re-iterate over the Cmake cache?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I wasn't sure how to set the title for this.

I basically have a code base that I build with `cmake`; now I would like to know if it's safe to invoke `cmake` itself on the same cache more than 1 time.

For example in the dir `/path` I'm building a cache with

```
cmake -DVAR=VALUE < more flags >
```

and then in a second step I invoke `cmake` again in the same directory `/path` with another set of flags

```
cmake -DANOTHER_VAR=ANOTHER_VALUE < more flags >
```

at this point there are some guarantees that what is inside `/path` is the result of both commands ? It depends on how the `CMakeLists` is written ?

My building system that I use over `cmake` could be simplified a little thanks to this steps, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to do this. Actually, when you change something in your CMakeLists.txt's and then run `make` in build folder, CMake invokes `cmake .` there to regenerate the cache.

Beside that, `-DVAR=VALUE` is an intended way for setting vars in the generated cache, as well as `-UVAR`.

The only exception is changing vars like `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. If you alter them with `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=newcc .`, CMake would wipe your cache and generate it from scratch.

Comment: ... because `cmake` takes a look at the timestamp and/or the checksum for the files ?

Comment: I think timestamp only, because `touch`ing files suffice.